# Remove scrollbar in iframe within div but not scrollable

Tags: jquery-mobile, iframe, scrollbar

Hi I'm working in Cordova/Phonegap and JqueryMobile. I have a div and a iframe here's the code. there is no cross domain  issue  in Cordova but in browser i cant show any one my working code but still here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skhurams/cepn831k/1/) code

```
    <div id="viewsites" class="viewsites">
<iframe class="clsIframe" src="http://www.google.com/" id="viewsite_iframe" width="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

i dont want to show scrollbars so i have set parent div overflow: hidden,
now problem in in iphone i cant drag the iframe site 
I want to hide scrollbars without stopping  scrollable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS:

```
iframe {
overflow:hidden;
}
```

In your iframe html tag:

```
<iframe src="" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```